# Binding multiple comboboxes to one filtered list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have three comboboxes all bound to the same list:

```
List:
a
b
c
```

I want to restrict the combobox dropdown so that when one item is already selected from one of the comboboxes, the user cannot set the same item more than once

```
cmb1: Available = a, b, c
cmb2: Available = a, b, c
cmb3: Available = a, b, c
```

User selects a on `cmb1`

```
cmb1: Available = b, c Selected = a
cmb2: Available = b, c
cmb3: Available = b, c
```

User selects b on `cmb2`

```
cmb1: Available = c Selected = a
cmb2: Available = c Selected = b
cmb3: Available = c
```

User changes `cmb1` to c

```
cmb1: Available = a Selected = c
cmb2: Available = a Selected = b
cmb3: Available = a
```

I've tried CollectionViewSource, getter properties but I am having trouble keeping each combobox aware of the changes of others. Any tips on how to do in wpf?

Comment: _but I am having trouble keeping each combobox aware of the changes of others_ - you should create own copy of list for every combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Collection per ComboBox

Create an instance of collection for each ComboBox and manage their items manually.

### IEnumerable per ComboBox

Let's say, you have a ViewModel with a `List` that contains all available items.
Also, you have `SelectedItem1`, `SelectedItem2` and `SelectedItem3` properties.

You can create simple `IEnumerable<T>` per each ComboBox and invoke `NotifyPropertyChanged` after one of selected items are changed:

```
public IEnumerable<string> List1 => List.Except(new[] { SelectedItem2, SelectedItem3 });
public IEnumerable<string> List2 => List.Except(new[] { SelectedItem1, SelectedItem3 });
public IEnumerable<string> List3 => List.Except(new[] { SelectedItem1, SelectedItem2 });
```

You need only update all your properties for selected items as follows:

```
private string _selectedItem1;
public string SelectedItem1
{
    get { return _selectedItem1; }
    set
    {
        _selectedItem1 = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem1));
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(List2));
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(List3));
    }
}
// etc
```

If your main list can be changed, you also should take care about updating your dependent lists:

```
List.CollectionChanged += (o, e) =>
{
    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(List1));
    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(List2));
    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(List3));
};
```

But this can adversely affect performance if you have a lot of items. After the invokation of the `NotifyPropertyChanged` your ComboBox should reinitialize all the items again.

Comment: How about comboboxes inside a itemcontrol where there are variable number of comboboxes?

Comment: @iH8WorkingWith.NetGraphics then you should describe this particular case in your (new?) post. It is hard to give you any suggestions without knowing the context and details of this problem.